# Entrada de dados sem ecoar na tela

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
entrada = input("digite a senha")
```

Se eu utilizar a função `input`, o que o usuário teclar será ecoado na tela. Como fazer de forma a nada ser mostrado no ecrâ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com o método `input()` creio que não dá. Mas pode fazer assim:

```
import getpass

p = getpass.getpass(prompt='digite a senha\n')
if p == '12345':
    print('YO Paul')
else:
    print('BRHHH')
print('O seu input foi:', p) # p = seu input
```

Simulando a verificação de uma hash:

```
import hashlib, getpass

key_string = b"12345"
hashed = hashlib.md5(key_string).hexdigest() # a hash vai estar numa base de dados/ficheiro num projeto real

p = getpass.getpass(prompt='digite a senha\n')
if hashlib.md5(p.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() == hashed:
    print('YO Paul')
else:
    print('BRHHH')
```

[Uma maneira significativamente mais segura (python 3.x)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html):

```
import hashlib, binascii, getpass

password = "12345"
# hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('metodo de hash', 'password', 'salt', 'custo/aumento de entropia')
pw = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode('utf-8'), b'salt' , 100000)
hashed_pw = binascii.hexlify(pw)

p = getpass.getpass(prompt='digite a senha\n')
input_hashed_pw = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', p.encode('utf-8'), b'salt', 100000)
if binascii.hexlify(input_hashed_pw) == hashed_pw:
    print('YO Paul')
else:
    print('BRHHH')
```

Comment: Obrigado, @Miguel. E se eu quiser não ter a senha no código mas sim um hash ou algo parecido para fazer o if, há uma maneira simples de fazer?

Comment: Claro que sim, dê-me um sec que já coloco um exemplo @PaulSigonoso

Comment: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/getpass.py", line 63
    passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.

Comment: Aqui a senha foi ecoada! Usei o IDLE

Comment: obrigado. Desculpe a quantidade de questionamentos!

Comment: Não tem importância @PaulSigonoso

Comment: Editado @PaulSigonoso , atenção que a hash nunca irá estar assim no seu código, leia o comentário à frente

Comment: Estranho que continua ecoando na tela:  Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/getpass.py", line 63
    passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
digite a senha

Comment: @PaulSigonoso, estranho... Aqui funciona, tanto em py2 como em py3, só o ultimo exemplo é que só funciona no python3.x

Comment: Estou usando IDLE: Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux

Comment: Ha, experimente correr no terminal: assim, `python3 caminho/para/este/script.py` @PaulSigonoso

Comment: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/getpass.py", line 63
    passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
digite a senha
123

Comment: Isso provavelmente depende de suporte do terminal.

Comment: Pois talvez seja isso @PabloAlmeida, eu só testei no terminal

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira bem simples de fazer isto é colocar pra gravar no `os.devnull`, assim será possível usar `input`:

```
import sys, os

#Salva o output
output_salvo = sys.stdout

# Define o ouput pra gravar no devnull    
f = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stdout = f

entrada = input("digite a senha")

# Restaura o output
sys.stdout = output_salvo
```